# Viewing/Listening IP camera video/audio in android phone

Tags: android

I would like to get started on this, but I can put everything on my mind right. So maybe someone could help me to know steps that are required to achieve this: I have laptop with integrated video camera and I would like to make it as IP camera and then embed it in my android app, that will let user to View that camera(my Laptop integrated camera) is streaming.

So far I came up with this:

1. I need to use software (webcamXP, webcam 7) to make my integrated laptop cam to an IP cam.
   (Maybe there is a way that I would not need to do that, because software developers put their logo on streaming video)
2. I will probably need some kind decoder? WebCam 7 let's me stream video as : Javascript, Motion JPEG, Flash JPEG stream, Flash FLV stream.
3. And that is, I don't know what I will need more, any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible do a little bit of research